# Ext.Net TextArea Height Attribute Bug?

Tags: .net, ext.net

I, recently, had a need to convert an Ext.Net TextField element to an Ext.Net TextArea element.  The problem is that the container in which the element lives has a set height and the TextArea extends past the container's boundaries.  I have tried applying several attributes to the element but none seem to work.  It appears that there is a bug that causes the TextArea to "collapse" to about 3px when applying any attributes affecting height (Height, MaxHeight, BoxMaxHeight, etc.).  My guess is that this is an issue when nesting the TextArea within a specific set of elements.

Markup (modified for brevity)

```
...
<ext:Viewport ID="viewport" runat="server" MonitorResize="true" Layout="Fit">
    <Content>
        <ext:BorderLayout ID="BorderLayout1" runat="server">
            <North Split="false">
                <ext:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Height="50" Layout="Fit" MonitorResize="true" Border="false">
                    <Items>
                        <ext:HBoxLayout ID="HBoxLayout2" runat="server" Pack="Center" OnLoad="ExtraControlsPanel_Load">
                            <BoxItems>
                                <ext:BoxItem>
                                    <ext:TextArea ID="extraTextField" runat="server" FieldLabel="Variable" Visible="false" ForceSelection="true" Editable="false" IDMode="Static" Width="250" LabelWidth="50" LabelPad="15" LabelAlign="Right">
                                    </ext:TextArea>
                                </ext:BoxItem>
                            </BoxItems>
                        </ext:HBoxLayout>
                    </Items>
                </ext:Panel>
            </North>
        </ext:BorderLayout>
    </Content>
</ext:Viewport>
...
```

As I mentioned:  if a "height" attribute is applied to the TextArea (regardless of the value), the element is "collapsed" to about 3px when rendered.  Has anyone worked with Ext.Net in any significant capacity that might have some insight here?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: It appears this question was asked, and a response provided on the Ext.NET Community forums (http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?18188-TextArea-Height-Issue)

Comment: @geoffrey.mcgill :) That was my question.  I tried pulling out the MonitorResize and Layout attributes to no avail.  I think the issue lies with the way that the page is rendered.  It is a very complex workflow.  I will most likely end up replacing the ext:TextArea element with a multi-line asp:TextBox or a standard textarea element.  Thank you for the comment, though.

Comment: ok, thanks for the update. Unfortunately neither of these threads were updated with a working sample demonstrating how to reproduce the issue, so I'll just assume your choice to use asp:TextBox or <textarea> has fixed the problem.

Comment: I did end up using an asp:TextBox element and that resolved the issue.  I am sure that this issue is fixed in Ext.Net 2.0 but upgrading is not an option for us right now :$.  Thank you, again.

Answer (score 0):

Updated on ext.net v4 , use  `Grow="true"` `Height="99"` with `ext:TextArea`

example

```
<ext:TextArea ID="txtUrl" Grow="true" Height="50" runat="server" FieldLabel="labelname" LabelWidth="87" Width="620" MaxLength="100" EnforceMaxLength="true" />
```